# AWS DynamoDB matrix doesn't work correctly

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cloudwatch

I am using dynamoDB and curious of this

When I see table matrix with period of 10, 30 seconds, it seems that it exceeds provisioned value

[image]

[image]

Then, when I see table matrix with period of 1 minutes, it doesn't reach provisioned value at all

[image]

I want to know why this happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a DynamoDB thing. It's a CloudWatch rendering thing.

Consumed capacity has a natural period of 1 minute. When you set your graph period to 1 minute everything is correct. Consumed is below provisioned.

If you change the graph period to 30 seconds, your consumed view adjusts and you see consumption that's double what's real. The math behind the scenes divides by the wrong period. Graph period of 10 seconds, you get 6x reality. Graph period of 5 minutes, you get 1/5th reality.

The Provisioned line isn't based on an equation involving Period so it's not affected by the chosen period.

Maybe someone can comment on why the user is allowed to control the Period of the view but it just messes things up when it doesn't match the natural period of the data.